# how to ignore future browser calls

Tags: r, debugging

When debugging, it is often useful to insert a `browser()` call in the code. If everything is fine and I would like to finish the function I can use `c` but if the browser is in a loop what would be the appropriate way to ignore this new calls?

I looked into `browser` help but didn't find something. I'm currently doing:

```
browser <- function(...){NULL}
```

Replacing the original browser function but it's not quite satifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `browser` in its own call and make it conditional:

```
breakpoint = function ()
    if (! exists('.break_disabled', parent.env(environment())))
        browser(skipCalls = 1L)
```

The `skipCalls` option is used because the `browser` call is nested inside a function rather than being called directly from where you want to break.

Now you just need to supply two functions to toggle breakpoints:

```
disable_break = function ()
    assign('.break_disabled', TRUE, parent.env(environment()))

enable_break = function ()
    if (exists('.break_disabled', parent.env(environment())))
        rm(.break_disabled, envir = parent.env(environment()))
```

It’s worth noting that just pasting the above functions into a script or an R session will pollute the global namespace with a hidden object. Normally I’d therefore define these functions in their own environment. However, for debugging purposes this should be fine.

Comment: Very elegant though it requires that you use breakpoint() all the time in place of browser

Comment: @cmbarbu Actually you could call this function `browser` and then inside call `base::browser`.

Comment: Right, so if I badly need to continue a loop I can use this browser <- your function calling base::browser() to do the trick.

Comment: Is `skipCalls` broken in R 3.4.1 and/or RStudio 1.1? Because here it doesn't do a thing. 1, 2, 20, I'm always dropped into the browser within the environment of `breakpoint()`.

Comment: @user2296153 It seems that way. This is probably due to the fact that RStudio installs its own handlers to enable interactive debugging. It’s worth raising the issue with their team … but unfortunately they don’ have a public bug tracker.